# Merged Records in SFDC CRM (Leads, Contacts, Accounts, etc.) & Impact on Salesforce Data Entry Event in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

Does someone know what happens in Journey Builder when records are merged in SFDC CRM for journeys that have Salesforce Data Entry events and entry criteria that are made of a data field update action?

For instance, if a SFDC CRM specialist merges several duplicate records in SFDC CRM, can those merge actions trigger journeys if the winning record is updated from the losing record with a data value that meets journey(s) entry criteria?

I do not have edit access in the SFDC CRM org that I work with to test it myself and I can't find proper documentation about this online. I'm keen to understand if other SFMC clients face this issue before I have SFDC CRM resources to help me test this. If merging records can trigger journeys, are there realistic solutions to circumvent this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If a record meets journey entry criteria, it will enter the journey, no matter how this was achieved.

This means it doesn't make any difference whether you have an automated process, or if someone manually goes through the records and merges them - if, in effect of those actions a record will meet journey entry criteria, it will enter the journey.

If you do not wish for those records to enter a journey, you could add an additional field (or use an existing one), for example, `MergedRecord__c = TRUE/FALSE` and add a condition to your journey to skip those records.

There are also a few Known Issues which could affect inserting records into a journey, but they should not be used as a workaround. You can read more here: [The Salesforce Data Event](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_salesforce_data_event.htm&type=5)